# non-terminating loop in line by line processing of a subprocess stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

> **In Python 3.7, what specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the loop is successfully terminated after the `subprocess` is finished running?**

The following code does run the subprocess and does print each line.  But the problem is that the `while true` loop never terminates because the console continues printing `b''` on every new line forever until I reboot the machine.

```
import subprocess  
proc = subprocess.Popen('python name-of-script.py',cwd="C:\\path\\to\\directory",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
while True:  
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if line != '':  
    #the real code does filtering here  
    print(line)
  else:
    break
```

After the meaningful output, the terminal keeps printing the following:

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

Comment: You must test against an empty byte string, not an empty unicode string. Note the b prefix when printing line!

Comment: How about `if line`?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin How would that look?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi How would that look?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin gonna try that now.  I have to reboot the machine, so it may take me a bit.

Comment: I meant replace `if line != '':` with `if line:`. You may also want to strip any endline character but it doesn't look like you have any.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin That solved the problem.  If you would like to write it up as an answer, i would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.  Are you also willing to explain how to remove the `b''` from the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your Popen object you are getting a byte stream as `stdout`.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout)

> If the `encoding` or `errors` arguments were specified or the `universal_newlines` argument was `True`, the stream is a text stream, otherwise it is a byte stream.

Therefore when you compare `line` to the empty **string** it will always be unequal because `line` can at best be an empty `byte` object, `b''`.

An empty byte object is a falsy value, so replacing `if line != ''` by `if line:` works for both empty string and empty byte object.

If later on you want `stdout` to be a text stream, the code doesn't break :)

```
while True:  
   line = proc.stdout.readline()
   if line:  
       #the real code does filtering here  
       print(line)
   else:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are comparing apples with pears.

`''` is not the same as `b''`